# How do I find the Context of a Dialog opened by a RecyclerView inside a TabLayout?

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview, dialog, android-context, android-tablayout

I am trying to open a dialog from the adapter of a recycler-view which is used in a fragment inside a tablayout. When I click on one of the rows of the recyclerview, the app crashes and I get the following error:

**android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application**

the activity opens, tablayout is declared, as well as viewpager... the fragment xml contains the recycler-view. `OrderActivity.getAllUserOrders()` is declaring the adapter, and sets the OrderActivity as its context.

Everything works as planned, until a click is made. At that point, the dialog is trying to open but the app crashes and I get the error above...

While debbuging, I found that "mActivityLifecycleCallbacks" value in mContext in the recycler-view adapter equals 2. It may have connection but I couldn't find what to do with that. I also found that it maybe possible that mContext points at an application context and not activity context...

Fragment:

```
public class orders_current extends Fragment {

    public orders_current() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_orders, container, false);

        [...]

        OrdersActivity.getAllUserOrders(getContext(), rootView, prefs.getInt("ID", 0), true);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

RecyclerView Adapter:

```
public class CustomOrdersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomOrdersAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext ;

    [...]

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomOrdersAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.layOrdersItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openDialogOrderItem(mData.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
            }
        });
    }

    [...]

    private void openDialogOrderItem(Order order) {
        final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_view_order);
        if(myDialog.getWindow() != null)
            myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        [...]

        myDialog.show();
    }

    [...]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after searching for some time. After debugging thoroughly I understood that the context the dialog got was actually application context, so I thought maybe giving the adapter a static value to work with.

In CustomOrdersActivity:

`public static Activity instanceActivity;`

Sending information in the onCreateView of the fragment, before declaring the adapter(just for a safer approach and better practice):

`CustomOrdersAdapter.instanceActivity = getActivity();`

And then later inside the dialog declaration:

`final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(instanceActivity);`

Simple as that.
Note: I did get a warning:

**Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)**

It didn't make any crashes or problems as far as I can tell...